Let's get critical: Mar 2014 Site Self-Evaluation
We all love Quantitative Finance Stack Exchange, but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.
The Site Self-Evaluation review queue is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.
Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? Post an answer below to share your thoughts and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Final Results

Book on market microstructure

Net Score: 3 (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Derivation of the Nelson-Siegel model and proof of arbitrage

Net Score: 2 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


What nonparametric methods exist for estimating intraday seasonalities?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)


Is there a difference between crossing network and ECN

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


Multifractal Model, Generating Sample Paths with Correlations between Assets

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)


How to eliminate border effects on Wavelet denoising?

Net Score: 1 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)


Is Cubic spline Interpolation on swaption Volatility arbitrage free?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)


Portfolio Optimization : Shrinkage of Covariance Matrix when data is available

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)


Lagged dependent variable, yes or no?

Net Score: 0 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)


probablity expiring in the money ..basic question

Net Score: -1 (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

